# Sorting the items in the desired order in lightning component aura:iteration tag

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration

I am displaying list of records using aura:iteration, now i want to put to arrow marks(up and down). if user clicks on any one record want to move that record in the selected direction either up or down.

For example there 5 records in the table, if user selects 3 rd one and clicks on up arrow on each click up arrow it has to move one step up.(How we are rearranging in multi select pick list values).

Please help on this.

Below is the code,

```
<lightning:card class="slds-p-around_medium" variant="narrow" title="{!$Label.c.BIC_AssessmentDetails}" iconName="standard:event">                
                <lightning:spinner aura:id="mySpinner" variant="brand" size="small" title="{!$Label.c.BIC_loading}" alternativeText="{!$Label.c.BIC_loading}" />    
                <lightning:accordion aura:id="accordion">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.mapinfo}" var="mapKey">
                        <lightning:accordionSection label="{!mapKey.key}">
                            <aura:iteration items="{!mapKey.value}" var="mapValue" indexVar="qnum" >
                                <ul class="slds-list_horizontal slds-card">
                                    <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-p-around_xxx-small" >
                                        <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" value="{!mapValue.Visibility__c}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-p-around_xxx-small">
                                        <ui:outputtext aura:id="checkbox" value="{!qnum+1}"/>.
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-text-align_left slds-p-around_xxx-small ">
                                        <ui:outputtext value="{!mapValue.BIC_Question__r.Question__c}"></ui:outputtext>
                                    </div>
                                </ul>                                    
                            </aura:iteration>  
                        </lightning:accordionSection>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:accordion>

            </lightning:card>
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Created a component to display records and tried to use Dueling Picklist -- Item Moved Within a List# with the SLDS. But unable to use it. Added the code in the description.

Comment: Any suggestions please help on this.